# How could I optimize this long line of "if" statements?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, refactoring

So, I am making a clicker game using Javascript, and I encountered that I needed to make a LOT, and I'm talking about 300, if statements. I did all the extremely tedious work, and got my game going.

In order to show you the problem I need to show you my game.
So basically, everytime I click on a button, one of ten images update.

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

The thing is, I made TONS of if statements for each number, and for each material that you can gather.

I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of all these if statements, and have the game work normally, or is there a way to optimize it.

Code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kr2xwyq/)
Most of the code goes like this:

```
if (A == 18) {
    document.getElementById("A1").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A2").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A3").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A4").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A5").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A6").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A7").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A8").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A9").src = "images/blocks/1A.png";
    document.getElementById("A10").src = "images/blocks/1A.png";
}
```

If you need a link to the actual game, let me know, since JSFiddle doesn't have my pictures.

Comment: Use refactoring process for setting up the SRC.And switch is one of the more readable way to convert and assign the values .

Comment: Switch statement is usually the better option when you find yourself using many if statements

Comment: @Fuzzybear I have no idea what that is, and how to do that. I am very new programmer. So I might need a bit more of a lead.

Comment: How about having a rules array something like `const rules = [ {rule: 18, imagePaths : [ {A1: "2A.png" }...{A10: "1A.png" }   ]}, {rule: 19,.....} ]` and then based on the rule number, read the imagePaths from the rules and set it accordingly.

Comment: If you find yourself copy-and-pasting a section of code *once* you should already stop and think what you are doing. Please don't do it 300 times, that's madness. There *always* is a better way than copy-and-paste.

Comment: You have currently accepted a solution that does not really solve the task. It's nothing but a rewrite that is just as tedious and repetitive as your own code; there's no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: Got it, I noticed it after a little bit, but didn't bother to change it. @Tomalak

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop to set A+i, but I suggest you set the same class for the dom with same content. You can use getElementsByClass or jQuery selectors, then set the src batchly.

```js
function changeSrc(){
  $(".type1").attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU4NZ.jpg?s=32&g=1");
}
```

```css
.type1 {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="type1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrQi.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
<img class="type1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrQi.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
<img class="type1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrQi.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
<img class="type1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrQi.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
<img class="type1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrQi.jpg?s=48&g=1"/>
<button onclick="changeSrc()">chang src</button>
```

Comment: How would I do this? I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: @TheVoidChaos I have make the demo, check it , you can use one code to batchly change the src with same  class, witch will save you many ifs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **jQuery**, you could try something like this:

```
if (A == 18) {
    $('[id^=A]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/blocks/2A.png");
    });

    $("#A9").attr("src", "images/blocks/1A.png");
    $("#A10").attr("src", "images/blocks/1A.png");
}
```

It works by grabbing every `img` that has an id starting with "A", then adding that specific `src` attribute on the end.

And for the two unique ones, it changes them once it is done.

I know it doesn't exactly solve the `if` statement problem, however, it will reduce your code drastically :-)

Comment: Looks pretty cool! I do not know how to use jQuery, therefore I am not using it.

Comment: oh, it's really simple to import. inside the `<head>` of your page, place this in there: `<script src="/squad/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` :-)

Comment: It makes life so much easier haha

Comment: I like your solution, very nice +1 and @TheVoidChaos easy to add jQuery to html page

Comment: Cool! Just got it. Should I just import the code, then I'm good?

Comment: @TheVoidChaos yep! simple as that :) no need to install anything on your OS

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are after refactoring.  You say you have many If statements, if these are comparing the same variable **A** then a switch statement can be used for example:

```
switch (A)
{
   case 18: 
    document.getElementById("A1").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A2").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A3").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A4").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A5").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A6").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A7").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A8").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A9").src = "images/blocks/1A.png";
    document.getElementById("A10").src = "images/blocks/1A.png";
    break;
   case 19: 
    document.getElementById("A1").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A2").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    document.getElementById("A3").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
    etc...
    break;

   default: 
       document.getElementById("A1").src = "images/blocks/2A.png";
       break;
}
```

It looks like you might want to create a function that passes in the elementID and returns a string for the image to as a second refactor.

Comment: Looks good! I am definitely gonna use this, but I have one question. What does the switch (A) mean?

Comment: so the code is taking your variable **A** and inspecting it's value to see if it matches the case value of **18** or **19** or defaulting to... if the case is met then the code will enter that case

Comment: @TheVoidChaos awesome pleased i could help :) do have a look at refactoring as per Caelan. suggestion for your src images

Comment: Cool, still importing everything, just want to make sure I'm doing everything right. http://imgur.com/a/odKeh

Comment: @TheVoidChaos yup look perfect for the switch :)

Answer (score 1):

How about having a rules array something like

```
const rules = [ 
      { rule: 18, imagePaths : [ {A1: "2A.png" }...{A10:    "1A.png" } ]}, 
        { rule: 19 , imagePaths:[....] }          
      ]
```

and then based on the rule number, read the imagePaths from the rules and set it accordingly. i.e., if selected value is 18, get the rules based on 18 from the rules array and then loop through `imagePaths` and set the src based on the value in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The only variable you have is a counter. Literally everything else can directly be calculated from that counter, if you only write down the rules.

The rules are,

#### Section values A, B and C

You want to create numeric ranges labeled A, B and C that go from 0 to 99 each and represent a different section of your counter, like so:

```
123456
CCBBAA, i.e. A = 56, B = 34, C = 12

  8921
CCBBAA, i.e. A = 21, B = 89, C = 0
```

This can be done by evenly dividing the number by a power of 100 and calculating [the remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (modulo) to 100:

```
(123456 DIV 100^0) MOD 100 = 56
(123456 DIV 100^1) MOD 100 = 34
(123456 DIV 100^2) MOD 100 = 12
```

In JS the integer division can be performed by rounding down. `Math.floor(140 / 100)` is not 1.4, but 1. The MOD operation is carried out by the % operator and the power operation is carried out by the `Math.pow()` function. So the above becomes:

```
Math.floor(123456 / Math.pow(100, 0)) % 100 // = 56
Math.floor(123456 / Math.pow(100, 1)) % 100 // = 34
Math.floor(123456 / Math.pow(100, 2)) % 100 // = 12
```

These are the values of your A, B and C sections directly derived from your counter value.

#### Ten images per section

You want to display each of those sections with ten images. Their names range from "0X" to "10X", where "X" is the respective section letter.

Assuming the section value is 37, you want the first 7 of the images to be "4X" and the last 3 "3X".

Again, we can derive the image name directly from the section value. Let's pick apart 37 by integer division and modulo into 3 and 7:

```
div = Math.floor(value / 10); // 37 => 3
rem = value % 10; // 37 => 7
```

Now the image name depends on what image we are manipulating. With a counter `k` from 0 to 9 we can decide whether the image name should start with 4 or 3.

```
imageName = (k < rem ? div + 1 : div) + letter;
```

For any `k` less than 7 we get "4X", the other get "3X".

In code, this is what it all looks like:

```
var total = 0,
    letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

function add() {
  total++;
  showState();
}

function showState() {
  var letter, range, value, imageName, div, rem, i, k;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    letter = letters[i]; // "A", "B", "C"
    range = Math.pow(100, i); // 1, 100, 10000
    value = Math.floor(total / range) % 100; // 0 .. 99

    document.getElementById(letter + "_Check").innerHTML = letter + ": " + value;

    for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
      div = Math.floor(value / 10); // 37 => 3
      rem = value % 10; // 37 => 7
      imageName = (k < rem ? div + 1 : div) + letter;
      elem = document.getElementById(letter + (k + 1));
      elem.src = "images/blocks/" + imageName + ".png";
    }
  }
}
```

That's all the code you need, and not a single line is copy-pasted.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4kr2xwyq/2/

Exercise: Find out if you can replace the images entirely by HTML/CSS (things like bar graphs are very easy to do in HTML, colors and element dimensions can be calculated and modified on the fly) or [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). This could in the end be easier to do than maintaining dozens of static image files.